# Why does java.time use 'of' instead of 'new' for dates?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

In the new date package in Java 8, we changed from using "**new** Date()" to "LocalDate.**of**()".

```
Date d = new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth);            //Old way
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);  //new way
```

When you want a new object you usually use the `new` keyword. This is an intuitive way to create a new object.

Sometimes, when you need a singleton with delayed initialization you can use a static method to get the instance. In this case you must call it `getInstance()` so developers know what to expect.

This new syntax makes the code less intuitive. It forces you to learn how to deal with specific objects instead of simply using them.

Are there any good reasons under the hood for this change?

Comment: It's called the builder pattern

Comment: The use of static methods like this is actually fairly common, especially with immutable classes. Also, the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) of `java.time` has a section named _Design notes (non normative)_, which says the `of` prefix is used for "static factory methods" as part of the hope of making the API more manageable.

Comment: Builder pattern helps you to set multiple variables in an immutable object before instantiate it.
In this case you set all the parameters in a single method, I don´t think it is the same case.

Comment: In the documentation is fairly clear, the point is: the change seems less usable than the previous version, so there must be a good reason to do this change, I wonder why

Comment: Keep in mind that not just `of` replaced `new`. There's also factory methods such as `LocalDate#ofInstant(Instant,ZoneId)`, `LocalDate#ofYearDay(int,int)`, `LocalTime#ofNanoOfDay(long)`, `LocalTime#ofSecondOfDay(long)`, `LocalDateTime#ofEpochSecond(long,int,ZoneOffset)` and so on. Reading those method names is much clearer than each class having 5+ constructors and having to determine which constructor is being used, and what it does, by tediously inspecting the arguments.

Comment: Factory methods are widespread in Java 8 and 9 and were also used in earlier Java versions. To mention a few: [`DatatypeFactory.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newInstance()) (since Java 1.5). [`Integer.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)). [`IntStream.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of(int...)).

Comment: Intuitive? I beg to differ. The old way isn’t more intuitive per se, but feels like it because your familiar with it. If there is a difference, `new` is intuitive for guaranteeing a new instance, while `of` is intuitive for not caring whether you get a new instance or an existing one. And since `LocalDate` and friends are immutable and value-based, you do not care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually static factory methods are preferred to constructors for several reasons,

- They have a name and that makes your code much more readable.
- static factory methods can have covariant return types, but
  constructor can't. This allows your API users to work with the interface, not the implementation, allowing you more room to change the concrete types in future releases. Also it reduces the conceptual surface area of the API too.
- Unlike constructors, static factory methods can do certain
  optimizations. On the contrary, every time you call a constructor,
  you expect it to return a new object. For an instance, check out
  the implementation of the static factory method
  `Collections.emptyList();`

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();

public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

It eagerly creates a singleton list and returns it on every invocation saving unnecessary overhead that would occur when constructors were used.

Due to the above reasons, static factories are preferred to constructors in today's programming. However, you can still use the `new` keyword with constructors as circumstances warrant.

Comment: And it allows to hide the actual implementation class, `EmptyList` in the example, from the public API. In case of `java.time`, these classes are further marked explicitly as [value-based](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) class.

Comment: Good catch, I have added it to the point 2. Appreciate it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with `new`: your code depends on the concrete class. Thus changing/evolving the code is a more difficult task.

A factory is much more manageable because (1) the user code is not dependant on the concrete type (2) the code that choose the concrete type is in a single place. Then the final code is much more secure/evolvable, etc.

`getInstance()` is not a good name for a factory, it is more the name of a singleton method. "get" is not intended to create something, just to get something already existant. `createInstance` or `create` is much more explicit for factories (many of them, even in Java are called such - examine `createImage` and alike). But alas, for reasons explicited by @slaw in comments, you need to be more precise to help the user choose between argument semantic, thus things like `createFromYears`, `createFromMinutes`, etc. That may be slightly verbose, then `of` seems to be a good compromise. Finally it is more easy (IMHO) to use `of*()` than `createImage()` with a lot of parameters to explain what arguments are...

Comment: `ZoneId.of()` is a nice example of not depending on the concrete class. What it gives you, is not a `ZoneId`, but an instance of a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

There a design pattern called `Fluent interface`, which allows "chaining" of methods, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java). It's supposed to very readable, imitating natural speech ("get x of y with z").

It's not especially *chaining* in your example (given it consists of only one method call), but it makes sense to use the same paradigm everywhere.

Comment: I didn’t get it exactly. What would have hindered method chaining with `new` like `new LocalDate(year, month, dayOfMonth).with(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY).atStartOfDay()`? If they had preferred this designed.